# How can I reduce my chances of XML corruption in large Word documents?

Tags: microsoft-word, xml, file-corruption

I am constantly creating large word documents (100+ pages). I have had occasional corruption issues in the past, but lately they seem to be happening more often and no one has any idea about what is causing it. I have version control in place so I can always recover an earlier copy of the document, but the most recent edits are always lost.

I have no real experience with XML at all but in the most recent case I tried to take a look at it to see if I can figure anything out. When I compared the corrupted file to the recovered document I was surprised to see that almost half the XML was entirely missing.

I'm sure figuring it out what caused this is nearly impossible but I'm wondering if anyone has experience with these types of issues and has suggestions or best practices on how to avoid this in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately can't give many help just a few general advice. Use latest version of Word, known bugs should be fixed in later versions. Avoid big and complex structures (tables, text boxes, charts...). It might help to split your document to smaller parts and only merge them when they're ready. ...